# PHP - Passing array with values from one page to another using $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

**Goal:** I want to pass an array with values from a page to another.

**Problem**: When it comes to the second page and i tried to print_r the array it doesn't have any values. and it gives me the this php notice on the second page:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: answers in Questionnaire_Category_2.php on line 17

here is my snippet code from the first page which is **Questionnaire_Category_1.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['Choice'])){ //When the user submits the answer
    $Answer[] = $_POST['Choice']; //All answers from the form will be placed in the array
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['answers'] = $Answer; //All values of the array will be assigned to the session variable 'answers'
    header("Location: Questionnaire_Category_2.php");
}
```

This is the snippet code of the second page named **Questionnaire_Category_2.php**

```
$ANSWER[] = $_SESSION['answers']; //Get all the values from the session and store it in array and also this is the Line 17 that causes a notice message
echo "<pre>"; print_r($ANSWER); echo "</pre>";
```

**Questions:**

1. Is my implementation from both pages are right?
2. If not, how do i properly pass an array along with its values from one page to another?
3. Is there another way to do it besides using $_SESSION?

Comment: Please make sure that you use `session_start()` befor you add/read values into/from the session

Comment: Put `session_start()` right after php tag

Comment: To answer your third question: yes, there is another way. Look into GET and POST variables. Definitely a better way to pass the data IMO

Answer (score 1):

do `session_start()` before adding and getting values in session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['answers'] = $ANSWER;
```

and

```
session_start();
$ANSWER = $_SESSION['answers'];
```

Comment: I did it and still the same error/s

Comment: After added into the sesssion just print and check that.

Comment: * Also be sure no other output happens before your `session_start();` line, as it likes to alter headers, and cannot do that if output has already begun.